# Oracle/PL-SQl:Pass on query result to another update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hi I am trying to update using PL/SQL based on one query result store the result and send this result to Update query but getting

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 24: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := ( ; not null range default character
```

Table:

```
    create table person(id number(10),stat char(1));
    insert into person(id,stat)values(123,'Y');
    insert into person(id,stat)values(123,'Y');
    insert into person(id,stat)values(345,'Y');
    commit;
```

Query:

```
DECLARE
  deptid  person.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO deptid 
     FROM person WHERE id = 345;
  IF SQL%FOUND THEN 
    Update person set stat='N' where id=deptid;
    commit;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dept Id: ' || deptid ||);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not wrap the whole thing into a single query instead?

Comment: I need the result returned from the select.which I have to pass to other insert staements. is it not possible to update like this ?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the `select` query. All it can return is one or several rows holding value `345`, which you already provide as a literal value to the `where` clause. And then you use that information to update the same table. For the question to make sense, you would probably need to show a more meaningful use case.

Comment: I am just giving an example where my first query returns 345 in reality I will get the id from one query which i need to be used across multiple update and insert statements.Just trying to keep question as small as possible

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RETURNING` clause in the `UPDATE`:

```sql
DECLARE
  deptid  person.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  UPDATE person
  SET    stat = 'N'
  WHERE  id = 123
  RETURNING MAX(id) INTO deptid;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dept Id: ' || deptid);
END;
/
```

Which, for your test data:

```sql
create table person(id,stat) AS
SELECT 123, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 345, 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the PL/SQL block outputs:

```
Dept Id: 123
```

And the table contains the values:

> ```
>  ID | STAT
> --: | :---
> 123 | N   
> 123 | N   
> 345 | Y
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=932e8427cd38f6fab43667ba5c3804d1)*

---

If you really want to use a `SELECT` statement then you need to make sure it only returns a single row:

```sql
DECLARE
  deptid  person.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT id
  INTO   deptid
  FROM   person
  WHERE  id = 123
  AND    ROWNUM = 1; -- FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY; 

  UPDATE person
  SET    stat = 'N'
  WHERE  id = deptid;
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dept Id: ' || deptid);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'No Dept Id!' );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4f630b85b3a6a02d93fd7e9e081e712)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I said I am trying to use result returned from select query.So first it should select and store in variable and pass that variable to update.

Comment: @Rocky4Ever Why? You do not need the `SELECT` query. Using `RETURNING` from the `UPDATE` gets exactly the same result (i.e. the `deptid` variable is set) and only hits the database once.

Comment: This is just an example data I gave my scenario is I should be able to use the result returned from select query in multiple update and insert statements

Comment: @Rocky4Ever You can use the returned value from the `UPDATE` statement in multiple `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements.

Comment: I executed the query got. ORA-06550: line 2, column 24: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: := ( ; not null range default character error http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0adbd/20

Comment: @Rocky4Ever The code I've posted runs on db<>fiddle on Oracle 11g and Oracle 18c; if you have an error in what you are running then you need to look at what has changed from my working code. I can't help with that as you haven't shared your code; only an error message. (And make sure that if you are running it in an IDE like SQL Developer that you run it as a script and not as a statement)

Answer (score 0):

Query that you posted as example has an error which cause code to fail.
Please remove extra pipes after deptid and before ')' in dbms_output command.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dept Id: ' || deptid);
```